# Responsive Images Not Responding

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I was tinkering around with making images responsive, however, I'm not seeing any change in my images, despite the fact that I've given them a predetermined `vw` which makes me think I have missed a step somewhere.

I currently have my imaged listed like so:

```
<img src="images/icon_1000x_large.jpg" alt="largeCodeIcon" srcset="images/icon_1000x_large.jpg 1000w, images/icon_500x_medium.jpg 500w, images/icon_200x_small.jpg 200w"
sizes="(min-width: 273px) 20vw, (min-width: 350px) 50vw, 100vw" >
```

Now in theory, at 273px the image should be 20vw and at 350, 50vw, but there is absolutely no change.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This shouldn't change how the image is rendered, rather what image is rendered. If you inspect the image you will see that the src varies based on screen size.

Comment: Which browser are you testing it with?

Comment: @SidTheBeard That;s just the thing though, nothing is changing in the src

Comment: One possibility: Once the browser has cached a larger image, it won't go and download smaller versions from a srcset: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30087595/3412322

Comment: @t.m. chrome 59.0

Comment: I think @DanielBeck has a point, I've had the issue in the past where I can see the change starting from the small image going up but once I go to the large image it doesn't go back down.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a little about this. I noticed others are using `max-width` not `min-width`. You may have multiple rules applying simultaneously using `min-width`. I'm not certain but these rules may not cascade, so the first matching rule could will win. Alternately you may be able to reverse the order and solve the problem that way.