# Img srcset not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying tow switch between different versions of same image with `srcset`, but in Chrome is not working. In Firefox is ok. Ater clearing the cache the result is the same

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 1170px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FOkWyOu.jpg"
         srcset="https://i.imgur.com/FOkWyOu.jpg 400w,
                 https://i.imgur.com/OXha4kY.jpg 767w">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you used developer tools and the network tab to see which image is used? I copied your code to codepen.io and the other image loaded when the screen got smaller. But you should also add the media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Resolution_switching_Different_sizes

Comment: In the Network tab when I am on smaller screen and refresh, the small image is loaded, but it is not visible in browser.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650327/responsive-images-srcset-not-working