# WordPress and the srcset image attribute

Tags: html, wordpress, srcset

I'm using WordPress 4.9.4.  Ive noticed that when viewing my blogs on a mobile, the images are far too wide.  I'm sure this never used to happen, but don't quote me on this.

Anyway, as part of debugging I noticed the srcset attribute on all my images.  And I understand what this functionality is providing by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650327/responsive-images-srcset-not-working#) post.

However, my images are not getting resized accordingly - they are staying at full size (I've tried in different browsers, clearing caches and chrome ingognito mode).  And I have a feeling it's because when they have been inserted into each post, they have 'height' and 'width' attributes on every image tag.

Moving forwards i can probably use [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-width-and-height-attributes-from-inserted-images/) method. But what do I do with all my historic posts?  Is including the height and width attributes good or bad practise in relation to srcset?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.your-post img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

if I understood you correctly.