# WooCommerce Product Thumbnails Not showed Properly

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have one weird issue into my Woo store. After latest update, Product Shop thumbnails start to show in unnusual way. Some images are shown fine, but some of them, are showed in full size. i want to make it all images to show like this:

[image showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxAQH.png)

Dimensions of "good" showed products are: 251px x 304px. This is my Woocommerce Thumbnails configrations too:

[woo configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKKrc.png)

I tryed to set this into CSS:

```
  .woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; // changed to 304px, but images makes smasshed.
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none
}
```

Any help, how to show all images fine? This is [link](https://reinigungsmittel-grass.de/autoshampoo-2/) form store.

Comment: Do you have a link to the store so we can see the code?

Comment: Yes i updated question with link to store.Sorry.

Comment: Was everything ok before the latest update?

Comment: not sure........

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like something is going wrong with the responsive images... have a look at this [issue for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650327/responsive-images-srcset-not-working)

Also the images look to be different sizes.

You could use CSS to make them more uniform but the images would look squished or out of proportion.

IMHO it best to try and keep the images similar sizes and proportion.