# Chrome dont recognize webp source in picture tag

Tags: html, responsive-images

I'm generating `picture` html tag with set of variants of image but when I opening it in chrome, browser still getting default png image

I tried different sets of srcset and sizes but no luck

```html
<picture>
    <source type="image/jpeg" sizes="(max-width: 320px) 290px, (max-width: 1200px) 290px, (max-width: 576px) 290px, (max-width: 992px) 290px, (max-width: 768px) 290px" srcset="http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.jpeg 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.jpeg 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.jpeg 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.jpeg 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.jpeg 290w">
    <source type="image/webp" sizes="(max-width: 320px) 290px, (max-width: 1200px) 290px, (max-width: 576px) 290px, (max-width: 992px) 290px, (max-width: 768px) 290px" srcset="http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.webp 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.webp 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.webp 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.webp 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.webp 290w">
    <img src="http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.png 290w" srcset="http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.png 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.png 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.png 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.png 290w, http://example.loc/images/r2yROrnu4lgNHq8i2058qUUBnydmgO6HoUcwurSQ_290.png 290w" media="(max-width: 320px) 290px, (max-width: 1200px) 290px, (max-width: 576px) 290px, (max-width: 992px) 290px, (max-width: 768px) 290px" class="img-fluid" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Try here to find answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650327/responsive-images-srcset-not-working

Comment: Problem about - why chrome deciding to get jpeg or png prefer to webp from picture sources and not about wrong image size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser takes the first `<source>` element it supports. Because all browsers support `image/jpeg` the second `<source type="image/webp">` gets always ignored.

To fix this issues you have to reverse the order of the `<source>` elements:

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" …>
    <source type="image/jpeg" …>
    <img …>
</picture>
```

Comment: I think - it works, changed render ordering and chrome got it, thanks