# Why does the browser doesn't seem to respect the srcset attribute?

Tags: html, wordpress, srcset

See the following `img` snippet:

```
<img width="768" height="514" 
  src="https://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/ottawa-815375_1280.jpg" 
  class="img-fluid article-img large wp-post-image" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" 
  srcset="https://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/ottawa-815375_1280.jpg 1280w, https://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/ottawa-815375_1280-300x201.jpg 300w, https://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/ottawa-815375_1280-1024x686.jpg 1024w" 
  sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 768px">
```

I opened the page in Chrome's responsive mode with a viewport width of 360px.

### What I expect

I would expect that the `srcset` part `https://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/ottawa-815375_1280-1024x686.jpg 1024w` matches as it's the first one bigger than 768px according to the `sizes` attribute.

### What actually happens

But Chrome loads the full size image `https://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/ottawa-815375_1280.jpg`.

Why doesn't Chrome respect the `srcset` attribute? What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wb69n0ct/) where you can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Have you checked this related thread?: [responsive images srcset not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650327/responsive-images-srcset-not-working). How is it behaving in other browsers apart from Chrome?

Comment: @Richard I checked the thread, it suggested clearing the cache which didn't help. In Safari (using Simulator iPhone 15) it's the same: the full size image is loaded. I guess there's some misunderstanding on my side about srcset but I don't know what.