# Responsive <img> tag retrieving wrong src

Tags: javascript, html, srcset

I've been trying to have a certain image tag behave responsively, by retrieving the most appropriate `src` depending on context.

The tag looks like this:

```
<img
    id="picimg"

    src="image.jpg"

    srcset="image-300x281.jpg 300w,
            image-1024x961.jpg 1024w,
            image.jpg 1664w"

    sizes="(max-width: 499px) 92vw,
            (min-width: 500px) 86vw,
            (min-width: 960px) 96vw, 96vw"
>
```

I have even tried this code snippet (found at : http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-part-2-img-required/) to check which `src` is in effect each time.

```
(function() {
  var currentSrc, oldSrc, imgEl;
  var showPicSrc = function() {
    oldSrc     = currentSrc;
    imgEl      = document.getElementById('picimg');
    currentSrc = imgEl.currentSrc || imgEl.src;

    if (typeof oldSrc === 'undefined' || oldSrc !== currentSrc) {
      document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML = currentSrc;
    }
  };

  // You may wish to debounce resize if you have performance concerns
  window.addEventListener('resize', showPicSrc);
  window.addEventListener('load', showPicSrc);
})(window);
```

However, the `src` seems to never change (it seems to always be `image.jpg`), regardless of the browser and its width.

I suspect that, by repeating the same default `src` as the last item in the `srcset`attribute, it may be affecting the outcome. Or else, maybe the determinant factor is the default size (last item in `sizes`).

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The is always the chance that I don't know how to test it.

Comment: I've found Chrome-Dev-Tools to misreport which image is being displayed when hovering over an element, but right clicking and going to "Open Image in New Tab" works. Alternatively, try marking your responsive images with a watermark during dev, just to ensure its working.

Comment: use png instead of jpg for a start!

Comment: does this codepen help? http://codepen.io/jtleathers/pen/IGytf

Comment: @GrahamPHeath, it seems to be a misreport, yes, because I tested in an actual phone, and the image that came was the smallest one. However, if I tried to what you said in desktop (even in a small viewport), the saved image would be the biggest, regardless.

Comment: @RachelGallen, why do you say so?

Comment: @ochi, that pen seems to deal with pixel density only, but thanks!

Comment: @GrahamPHeath, also, the watermark suggestion is very useful, thanks

Comment: have you considered using the picture element? http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/m3fo5p5n/

Comment: @RachelGallen I followed the suggestions in this set of articles (http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-definitions/) , and since my case doesn't fill the "art direction" case scenario, I stuck with srcset :)

Comment: @LeonardoBaptistaLopes fair enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the syntax is working correctly (it tested successfully on actual mobile browsers).

I just don't know exactly why the script to check the `src` didn't work properly.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you start out with a wide window such that the biggest image is the most appropriate one, then Chrome/Opera will not download a smaller image when making the window smaller. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28368483/729033

Comment: I understand that, thank you. However, I tried to check by loading the page on a smaller screen and it didn't work in Chrome or FF.

Comment: I must say, however, that it worked on mobile Chrome and Firefox :)